# How to turn %s into {0}, {1} ... less clunky?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have to take a string containing placeholders for later substitution, like:

```
"A %s B %s"
```

And turn that into:

```
"A {0} B {1}"
```

I came up with:

```
def _fix_substitution_parms(raw_message):
  rv = raw_message
  counter = 0
  while '%s' in rv:
    rv = rv.replace('%s', '{' + str(counter) + '}', 1)
    counter = counter + 1
return rv
```

That works, but it feels super clunky, and not at all "idiomatic" python.

How would a well, idiomatic python solution look like?

Updates for clarification:

- the resulting strings aren't used within python. I **do** need the counter numbers in there! (so `{}` isn't good enough)!
- I only need to care about `%s` strings, as the messages are guaranteed to only use `%s` (no `%i %f` whatsoever)

Comment: "re.sub" can take a function as replacement to dynamically replace with numbered braces. By the way: Replacing with {} without numbers would work as well.

Comment: When you have a working solution and you would like to improve it, please consider codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: @kojiro It isn't working for me, due to "too clunky" ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would do what Reznik [originally](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58376488/1011724) suggested and then call `.format` on that:

```
def _fix_substitution_parms(raw_message: str) -> str:
    num_to_replace = raw_message.count("%s")
    python_format_string_message = raw_message.replace("%s", "{{{}}}")
    final_message = python_format_string_message.format(*range(num_to_replace))
    return final_message
```

Comment: this will work only if you have 2  `%s` in the text?

Comment: @CharifDZ and Aran-Fey - see the edit. You just count them before hand...

Comment: Looks like a good compromise ... readable, but not too fancy.

Answer (score 8):

Use `re.sub` with a lambda function for reapplying the substitution once for each element, and `itertools.count` for getting numbers sequentially:

```
import itertools
import re

s = "A %s B %s"

counter = itertools.count()
result = re.sub('%s', lambda x: f'{{{next(counter)}}}', s)
print(result)  # 'A {0} B {1}'
```

Remember to wrap this in a function to perform this operation more than once, since you'll need to refresh `itertools.count`.

Comment: Nice, albeit I find it a bit "obscure" ;-)

Comment: @GhostCat it's not obscure, counter is a generator when ever you call `next(counter)` it produce the next value, I always forget about this generator really nice answer

Comment: @GhostCat regex and functional programming in the same line :-P I guess the "obscurity" depends on how much you're used to these tools.

Answer (score 3):

I think that shoudl work

`rv.replace('%s','{{{}}}').format(*range(rv.count('%s')))`

Comment: @GhostCat don't be tempted by one-liners, remember that people have to maintain code

Comment: @Dan I know. But I less code is also less code to maintain.

Comment: It's not less though, it's just harder to debug and harder to a future dev to read. This answer is pretty close to being identical to mine, it has the same function calls (swapping replace for split and join) but what if there's a problem in an intermediate step? How would you isolate it. And which is quicker of r a new dev to understand what it does just from the code. I really recommend you don't put this much logic in a single line.

Comment: Not a nice one-liner. `X.join(Y.split(Z))` is just a convoluted way of writing `Y.replace(X, Z)`, and there's no need to wrap the `range` call in `list(...)` either.

Comment: @Aran-Fey oh interesting, I didn't realise you could use `*` directly on a range object. Also, this answer is now identical to mine :)

Comment: @Dan yes, sorry about that, (only in one line now) :)

Answer (score 2):

Using `re.sub` for dynamic replacing:

```py
import re

text = "A %s B %s %s B %s"


def _fix_substitution_parms(raw_message):
    counter = 0
    def replace(_):
        nonlocal counter
        counter += 1
        return '{{{}}}'.format(counter - 1)
    return re.sub('%s', replace, raw_message)


print(_fix_substitution_parms(text))  # A {0} B {1} {2} B {3}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this doesn't account for escaped placeholders (`%%s`) - if that's a concern, you can use the regex `r'(?<!%)%s'` instead.

Comment: If you allow the stupid question: what are the `{{{}}}` actually about?

Comment: String formating to escape `{` we don't do `\{` like usual we do `{{`.

Answer (score 1):

Using a generator:

```
def split_and_insert(mystring):
    parts = iter(mystring.split('%s'))
    yield next(parts)
    for n, part in enumerate(parts):
        yield f'{{{n}}}'
        yield part

new_string = ''.join(split_and_insert("A %s B %s"))
```

Answer (score -3):

Have you try with .format?

string.format(0=value, 1=value)

So:

`"A {0} B {1}".format(0=value, 1=value)`

Comment: How does this help anyone turn `%s` into `{}`?